# turn data in json from wide to long format using trino

Tags: sql, json, hive, trino, starburst

ok so i have an s3 folder with a lot of json files in it. the json files look like this:

```
{responses:[{
  "QID1":3,
  "QID2_1":4,
  "QID2_2:"hallo"
},...]}
```

i do not know how many distinct QIDxy values there are. I know that all the keys i am interested in start with "QID" followed by some combination of digits and underscores.

I use trino to query those folders. So for this example i would normally do it like this.

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
  responses ARRAY(
    ROW(
      QID1 int,
      QID2_1 int,
      QID2_2 varchar
    )
)
WITH (
  format = 'json',
  external_location = 's3://xyz'
);
```

But in this case i do not know which QIDs - column names - there are. So I would like to dynamically build a long format, that has all the keys of the json objects in it an should look like this.

| question_id | answer_int | answer_str |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QID1 | 3 | null |
| QID2_1 | 4 | null |
| QID2_2 | null | "hallo" |
| ... | ... | ... |

any idea how i can do this without knowing the concrete column names and without preprocessing the json files. Maybe there is something like trino integrated jslt that could be used.